# How with pint can I remove space after negative “!” symbol?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-pint

How with laravel/pint 1.4 can I remove space after negative “!” symbol ?

Not :

```
if (! self::$wasSetup) {
```

But :

```
if (!self::$wasSetup) {
```

I suppose that last is psr-12 rule...

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per `PHP-CS-Fixer` , [Rule not_operator_with_successor_space](https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/v3.0.1/doc/rules/operator/not_operator_with_successor_space.rst)

Logical `NOT operators (!)` should have one trailing whitespace.

So by default, one trailing whitespace is enabled. To disable white space after NOT operators then you should create a `pint.json` file in the root folder

```
{
    "preset": "laravel",
    "rules": {
        "not_operator_with_successor_space": false
    }
}
```

[image]