# Laravel Pint json config not wokring

Tags: laravel, laravel-pint

I've been playing around with Laravel Pint and I can't seem to make it work the way I want.

My goal is to have the curly brackets inline with class or function

so instead

```
function test() 
{

}
```

I want to have a format like this

```
function test() {

}
```

I have this on `pint.json` but doesn't change anything.

```
{
    "preset": "laravel",
    "braces": {
        "position_after_functions_and_oop_constructs": "same",
        "position_after_anonymous_constructs": "same"
    }
}
```

I event tried using `psr12` preset and still does not change anything

```
{
    "preset": "psr12"
}
```

Additionally, I'd like to know how I can allow this format

```
if ( !$num ) 
    return;
```

it changes to this after running pint, (it removes the space between `if` condition and added a space after `!` and wrap the state with brackets)

```
if (! $num) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule in a `pint.json` will be

```
{
    "preset": "laravel",
    "rules": {
        "not_operator_with_successor_space": false,
        "curly_braces_position": {
            "functions_opening_brace": "same_line",
            "classes_opening_brace": "same_line"

        }

    }
}
```

As per [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer) Rule, use  [curly_braces_position](https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/master/doc/rules/basic/curly_braces_position.rst)

[image]

[image]

Ref: [How with pint can I remove space after negative “!” symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75308076/how-with-pint-can-i-remove-space-after-negative-symbol)

Comment: Thanks, and relating to `if` statement without brackets, I found out its not supported by PHP-CS-FIXER https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/2780